# How to check if node is a leaf in binary tree (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, binary, binary-tree

I need to check if a node is a leaf in my binary tree. This is my current code.

It sends me an error message saying:
"hw3_71937.hs: C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\���\��� HASKELL\hw3_71937.hs:(22,1)-(25,91): Non-exhaustive patterns in function isLeaf"

I do not know how to recursively check the next node if it is a leaf. Any help will be thanked.

Comment: What if this is called with `isLeaf node Empty`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guard:

```
  | tree == Empty = False
```

can *never* be true, since in the head of your clause:

```
isLeaf node tree@(Node el left right)
```

you say that this is a `Node`, not an `Empty`. This is also the case that you did not cover: in case you pass an `Empty` (and eventually you can pass an `Empty` due to recursion), no pattern will match.

That being said, I think you make this too complicated. You can write this as:

```
isLeaf :: Eq a => a -> BTree a -> Bool
isLeaf _ Empty = False
isLeaf x (Node x' Empty Empty) = x == x'
isLeaf x (Node _ l r) = isLeaf x l || isLeaf x r
```

or with a `where` clause:

```
isLeaf :: Eq a => a -> BTree a -> Bool
isLeaf x = go
    where go Empty = False
          go (Node x' Empty Empty) = x == x'
          go (Node _ l r) = go l || go r
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it fixed the problem. I hadnt noticed that the guard will never execute.

Comment: @АтанасИванов please accept this answer if it's correct